# Jqgrid after filter

Tags: jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid with multiselect : true,by some "check box" filters.

If i check the all rows.Then i unchecked some check boxes(some rows will be filtered) for that

it filtered correctly,but selection back ground color is lost(change to white).

Can any one help me,How to stop this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to save the rows ids in an array using the onSelectedRow method and after the filter is done select the desired rows back.
I'm sure it's not the best idea but this workaround can unblock you.

Hope it helps